# SharePoint 2007 Update List Item Workflow

Tags: list, workflow, 2007

I have 2 lists that need to run in parallel. When list 1 gets submitted, it automatically needs to fill in certain fields in list 2.

List 1 can be completed on its own as well, however list 2 cannot.

I have set up the 'Create list item' workflow which is all working fine.

However, when items in list 1 get amended, I need it to automatically update in list 2.

I have tried the 'Update List Item' workflow, however there will be no way to determine what item needs to be updated, because list 1 can also be completed on it's own (without the need for list 2) so the ID's will not match.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hidden field in list 1 and list 2 that has a unique id. So when a item is created in list 1 the hidden id will be put in the item in list 2 by the `Create List Item` Workflow. Then when you need to update you can search list 2 for that unique hidden id.

Comment: Thanks Belmer. Would this hidden field need to be a calculated column? If so what would the formula need to be?

Comment: It would not need to be calculated you just need it to be a unique id for that item between the two lists. This could be done with a calculated column or you could include the column in the create form and have the user just input one.

Comment: I wouldn't use a calculated column - I would have the workflow populate your hidden field with the ID of the list item in the other list which needs updating.